# Unfound linux partition after installing windows 10

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, windows-10, partitioning

I had win7 alongside ubuntu 16.04, having a problem with win7 boot, I installed win10 and launched boot repair (macrium reflect) from there (win7 was fixed).

I think, I made a big mistake, cause now I can't find linux partition when launching linux from usb, using fdisk -l.
Here is the log info of boot-repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25567488/
Did I just lose all my files ?!
Is there a way to recover my files, I had important files and docs that I'd like to get back.
I would appreciate any help.
Does linux takes system image routinely ? 
Thanks

Comment: Please explain exactly what steps you took to "repair" Windows.  But in general, it sound like you blew away your Linux partition, and as such, the files that were in it. There are lots of data recovery questions on here, and as-is this one is too broad.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007   Added link to pastbin containing the log to boot-repair

Comment: @Ramhound added the log of boot-repair and the name of the program

Comment: Your Ubuntu is gone. If you don't need any personal file from there, just reinstall as before (shrink the partition if needed). If you do need to recover files the **stop using that drive at once**, run a live session (Ubuntu), install and use Testdisk/Photorec (and hope for the best).