# Recovering a lost linux partition?

Tags: linux, partitioning, data-recovery, testdisk

After installing windows I think I lost my linux partition (my other question here:[Unfound linux partition after installing windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1251568/unfound-linux-partition-after-installing-windows-10))

I run TestDisk from usb, and I got, when choosing "Analyze":https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNQlA.jpg

After choosing "Quick Search": https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX8ob.jpg , which is I think my lost partition (Linux)
I know this is probably a very noobish question, but I really want to recover as much data as possible (or the hole partition), hence I don't want to make a mistake.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Isn't testdisk able to restore the partition it found? You could also try gparted. It can find lost partitions as well but it allows you to copy files of the lost partition without modifying your partition table so it seems less risky.

Comment: @SpiderPig I'm not sure, right now I'm doing a deep search, do you mean I copy the files to an external hard drive (to avoid damaging any data in the process) ?